# simpleCart quantity not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, simplecart

I tried having simpleCart shopping cart display name, price and quantity using the following line

```
<a class="item_add" href="javascript:;"> Add to Cart </a></p>
```

as given in documentation and in sample index file included in simplecart.js download. That did not show item name.

Index file also included alternative formulation:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="simpleCart.add({name:'baby lion', price: 34.95,size:'tiny',thumb:'e.png'});" >add to cart</a>
```

which added the name, price but wrong quantity. Adding quantity attribute either directly (i.e. `quantity: Quantity`) or by getElementById method (i.e. `quantity: document.getElementById("item_Quantity").value`) resulted in errors.

My shopping cart's columns are set up as follows:

```
simpleCart({
    cartColumns: [

{ attr: "name" , label: "Item"},  

{ attr: "price" , label: "Price", view: 'currency' } ,

{ view: "decrement" , label: false , text: "-" } ,

{ attr: "quantity" , label: "Qty" } ,

{ view: "increment" , label: false , text: "+" } ,

{ attr: "total" , label: "SubTotal", view: 'currency' } ,

{ view: "remove" , text: "Remove" , label: false }
    ]
});
```

How can I show both name and quantity?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer, I failed to list each item as

```
<li class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
```

Pretty dumb error but it threw me off as other attributes were showing in the cart. It works now.